# How to add value to specific position in 2d array in C

Tags: c

I need to write a function that has two parameters x, y. x and y are positions of the matrix (2d array).
also, I need to print that matrix to the console. I must use pointers...
how can I add to 2d array in the C program? I found it for Java, but not in C.
Thanks.
I tried this, but this only prints a simple matrix...

---

```
int m = 5;
int n = 5;

// dynamically create array of pointers of size m
int** arr = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));

// dynamically allocate memory of size n for each row
for (int r = 0; r < m; r++)
    arr[r] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

assign(arr, m, n);

// print 2D array
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("[%d][%d]", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}





// deallocate memory
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    free(arr[i]);
free(arr);
```

---

Comment: In this expression statement assign(arr, m, n);
 m and n are not positions in arrays. They are sizes of arrays. So it is unclear what you need.

Comment: `i need to write a function which have two parameters x, y ... x and y are position of matrix (2d array).` --> I don't understand what this function is supposed to do.  Can you please write the function declaration and a description of what is does.

Comment: I am sorry, so i need to write a function, which have 2 parameters (specific position of matrix), what value wil fill in that specific position it doesnt matter, could be static. 

like this: 

void function (int x, int y){
matrix {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}
add_value (position (1.1), value 10);
printf {10, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}

}...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you have wrote for dynamically creating array is OK.

to add item in specific position you need to like following:

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
    scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]); // i-row, j-col
 }
}
```

to print item from the specific position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf("[%d]", arr[i][j]); // -- single %d, since arr[i][j] points to single item
}
```

}

if you want to add item over function, say assign, you can do like this:

```
void assign(int ** arr, int x, int y){
   arr[x][y] = value; //value you can send through parameter, or you can declare the variable as globall
}

assign(arr, x, y);
```

here is the full code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  void assign(int ** arr, int x, int y, int value){
       arr[x][y] = value;
  }
  int main() {
     int n=5, m=5;
     int** arr = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));

     for (int r = 0; r < m; r++)
       arr[r] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    
     assign(arr, 0, 3, 34);
     assign(arr, 0, 2, 98);
     assign(arr, 1, 1, 88);

     // print:
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
          printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
     }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I am stupid.... i tried to put your part of code to mine and it doenst act like I expected, it just went to error....

may i ask you to post whole code with mine too? thanks...

Comment: edited; but you should try, take a break, and try.. :)

Comment: Thank you very very much, i am fighting with this more than 8 hours (yesterday and today), my brain is dead....

Comment: that's nice, keep that motivation. :) good luck to the future.

Comment: If you want to start at (integer) zero, consider using `calloc` for the second `malloc` call or explicitly set them.